# ldap_matching_rule_in_chain display nested memberOf attributes

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I have two levels of groups in my active directory e.g.

- GroupA contains Group1 and Group2
- GroupB contains Group2 and Group3
- GroupC contains Group1 and Group3
- Group1 contains User1 and User2
- Group2 contains User1 and User3

LDIF looks something like this:

```
dn: CN=GroupA ....
member: CN= Group1 ..
member: CN= Group2 ..

-----
dn: CN=Group1 ....
member: CN=User1 ..
member: CN=User2..
.
memberOf: CN=GroupA ...
memberOf: CN=GroupC ...

----

dn: CN=User1....
memberOf: CN=Group1 ...
memberOf: CN=Group2 ...
------
```

What I need is to retrieve users with all their parent groups in the memberOf field.

With ldap_matching_rule_in_chain, I am able to retrieve for examples all members of GroupA and that's exactly what I need. But I also need to have GroupA in a memberOf attribute of the users. Alas, users only have their direct groups in the memberOf attribute. According to [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/windows/win32/ad/security-properties?redirectedfrom=MSDN) :

> Be aware that this attribute lists the groups that contain the user in their member attribute—it does not contain the recursive list of nested predecessors. For example, if user O is a member of group C and group B and group B were nested in group A, the memberOf attribute of user O would list group C and group B, but not group A.

I looked into TokenGroups which allows to get the ID of all the groups but the problem is that it only works with one entry and at scope "base" level not "subtree". But I need to query all users in one request and get all their groups (direct and nested) in the attributes.

I hope my problem is clear. Thank you in advance.

Best regards,

Comment: There is no way to do what you're asking. You cannot search for multiple users and include the recursive group membership for each result. What are you trying to do with that information anyway?

Comment: I am trying to configure LDAP for Apache NiFi (https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html#ldapusergroupprovider) and it is the only way to get it to work with my AD structure. I am at an impasse and getting all the groups in the memberOf field is the only solution.

Comment: I've never used that software, but I doubt that's the only way since it simply isn't possible. That documentation you linked to seems to suggest that it will search for groups separately. There is an [apache-nifi](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/apache-nifi/info) tag on Stack Overflow. You can try asking about what you're trying to do with it and see if someone familiar with Apache NiFi can help.